# How to update non sequential groups in numpy data with keeping the order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I have a two datasets which are originated from same dataset. The original dataset is divided as `target_data` and `input_data` given below:

```
target_data, type:numpy.ndarray
[12,
 14,
 11,
 17,
 9,
 10,
 7,
 2,
 21,
 27]

input_data, type: pandas.DataFrame
group_name
   'A' 
   'B'
   'B'
   'A'
   'A'
   'B' 
   'A'
   'B'
   'B'
   'A'
```

Here, I am trying to update `target_data` for each group defined in `input_data`. For example, for `group 'A'`, I need `target_data` to be updated with 2 times of current values. For `group 'B'`, I need `target_data` to be updated with 4 times of current values. The desired `target_data`:

```
target_data, type:numpy.ndarray
[24,
 56,
 44,
 34,
 18,
 40,
 14,
 8,
 84,
 54]
```

Is there any way to do it pythonic way?

Comment: both are numpy arrays? not in a pandas dataframe, right?

Comment: target_data, type:numpy.ndarray, input_data, type: pandas.DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
map_d = {'A':2,'B':4}
array * df['input_data'].map(map_d).values
```

Comment: I dont have an access to original data and I need to update target_data which is in numpy.ndarray.

Comment: @user3104352 see the update